# Bootstrap navigation (on mobile) behind my footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating my website with bootstrap but I do have 2 problems.
My layout is build like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">...</div>
    <div id="content">...</div>
    <div id="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

In the header I've got my navigation which resizes to the page perfectly at the moment.
Though my first problem is: once I go into mobile mode (resize the page) and extend the navigation the navigation expansion is behind my footer.

My other problem is that my footer (once the columns go under each other) won't expand the color all the way to the bottom. The color stops after the 446px I gave the footer.

I've tried solving these problems multiple ways but I wan't able to.
My website (WIP of course) is right here: "removed url", I could upload the css here also but I think (because it's very small) it's easier to look at the [css file][2] and the index file itself.

This solution (which doesn't work really good) isn't done with bootstrap. I also tried using the Sticky footer, but that also didn't work out.

Thanks in advance,

Marc

Edit: As you can see down below the navigation issue is fixed. The only problem left is that the color isn't expanding when the footer expands.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your footer something like:

```
#footer{
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    padding-top:80px;
    height: 550px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background: #303030 url(../images/templatemo_footer.png) repeat-x top;
    color: #999;
    z-index: -20;

}
```

One last try:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 980px) {
    #footer{
        height: 650px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what it's supposed to do, but nothing has changed.

Comment: The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order. But I guess that didn't work..

Comment: Now you've changed the answer the navigation is working. However the footer isn't aligning at the bottom of the page anymore. Now it has a white bar under it (My screen is big). With the position: absolute; it wasn't there.

Comment: Bring back the absolute position and just keep the z-index. (Sorry I am still learning CSS -.-")

Comment: Thanks, the problem with the navigation is now fixed! Do you also have any clue what the problem could be with the white background once you go into mobile view (under the grey footer?)?

Comment: 99% is because of the Twitter widget. It was not meant to be that "tall" and the footer does that. You can try to remove it when the screen is small or fix the footer by adjusting it. Tbh I can't play around without the code :P

Comment: I removed the twitter widget and added a lot of <br />'s. Though the background image + color still stops after the 446px (as you can see). Btw, you can edit the code with 'Inspect element' in Chrome.

Comment: I am a FF user and currently away from my PC :P a simple solution would be to change the `height: 550px;` under #footer

Comment: Okay, that wouldn't change my problem because then it's first of all too big in my desktop view and still too small in my mobile view. I will try to change this tommorow, this looks like a 'easily fixable' thing. (which I couldn't fix today, but I will try again!) Thanks for helping!

Comment: I added one last try mate if you are not off to bed yet :) You are welcome and sorry for not being a greater help -.-"

Comment: This does work! Thanks, it isn't a way I would do it (and I would prefer it) but I don't know any other way. I will use this untill I got a better solution. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I am sure there is a better way but I can't think of anything else atm :P You are welcome xD